# Conditional rendering page shows loads wrong page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using react and nextjs for a project. Essentially, if it's past the expired date, the page should show an expired page, if not show the existing page.

What is happening is that:

1- I'm on the Black Friday page before it's expired

2- Time expires

3- I refresh

4- it loads the Black Friday page (incorrect, it should only load expired).

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const blackFridaylugs = await ContentfulApi.getBlackFridaySlugs();

  const paths = blackFridaySlugs.map((item) => ({
    params: { slug: item.slug }
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking"
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false, params, previewData }) {
  const page = await ContentfulApi.getBlackFridayPromoBySlug(params.slug, {
    preview,
    enviroment: previewData?.enviroment
  });

  const expiredPage = await ContentfulApi.getPageContentBySlug(
    "expired-page",
    {
      preview,
      enviroment: previewData?.enviroment
    }
  );

  const globalSettings = await ContentfulApi.getGlobalSettings({ preview });

  return {
    props: {
      page,
      expiredPage,
      globalSettings
    },
    revalidate: 100
  };
}

function BlackFridayPages({ page, expiredPage, globalSettings }) {
  if (!expired) {
    return (
      <ExpiredPage expiredPage={expiredPage} />
    );
   }

  return (
    <>
     <BlackFridayPage /> 
    </>

  );
}


export default BlackFridayPages;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in function **BlackFridayPages**

- I don't know why **!expired** condition showing **ExpiredPage**
- **expired** variable does not exists and not throw exception so it will display incorrect