# Prerender a page but have the correct conditional page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to pre-render my Black Friday pages.  But when it is expired, it should show an expired page instead.

The issue with the code below is that it is loading the Black Friday page, then the expired page (presumably because it takes longer). The end result is the user gets an expired page with mixed styling from the Black Friday page styling. How do I fix this?

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const blackFridaylugs = await ContentfulApi.getBlackFridaySlugs();

  const paths = blackFridaySlugs.map((item) => ({
    params: { slug: item.slug }
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking"
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false, params, previewData }) {
  const page = await ContentfulApi.getBlackFridayPromoBySlug(params.slug, {
    preview,
    enviroment: previewData?.enviroment
  });

  const expiredPage = await ContentfulApi.getPageContentBySlug(
    "expired-page",
    {
      preview,
      enviroment: previewData?.enviroment
    }
  );

  const globalSettings = await ContentfulApi.getGlobalSettings({ preview });

  return {
    props: {
      page,
      expiredPage,
      globalSettings
    },
    revalidate: 100
  };
}

function BlackFridayPages({ page, expiredPage, globalSettings }) {
  const blackFridayEndDate = new Date('2023-02-20') //Change this to test
  const now = new Date();

  const expired = blackFridayEndDate < now

  if (expired) {
    return (
      <ExpiredPage expiredPage={expiredPage} />
    );
   }

  return (
    <>
     <BlackFridayPage /> 
    </>

  ); //no extra conditional because I want it pre-rendered. Am I not allowed to do this?
}


export default BlackFridayPages;
```

Replicate bug:

1- User loads bf page when not expired

2- let the page expired

3- refresh

4- User gets the expired page (but it is not styled correctly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional rendering page shows loads wrong page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75431818/conditional-rendering-page-shows-loads-wrong-page). You asked the same question there, and marked an answer you received as accepted, which means you believe it solved the problem. Why are you asking again in a duplicate question?

Comment: @KenWhite, no, the other question was able to fix how it was loading their wrong page. (wrong expired conditional). but the issue now is that it is showing the expired page, but it still has the preloaded page. So it looks off

Comment: @KenWhite, I see the confusion. I edited the last question to match what I was asking. This question can stay perhaps, since it will help me with the next bug?